# CUBA Platform Is it possible to prevent tabs to be opened more than once?

Tags: cuba-platform

I am trying to prevent certain "cuba"tabs from opening more than once. Is it possible to stop an Edit-Screen to open, if it already is opened in another tab?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

You can control the behavior of a screen being opened multiple time via the controller annotation MultipleOpen. See: https://files.cuba-platform.com/javadoc/cuba/7.2/com/haulmont/cuba/gui/screen/MultipleOpen.html

For Editors this is not defined to my best knowledge, because there it normally means that multiple instances of the screen show details for multiple records.

But even this you can probably programmatically prevent inside the main screen / the editor itself.

Comment: Since it does not work with Editors - how do I do it programmatically?